# Searching for recursive pattern within a string

Tags: perl

Using Perl, I want to search a string of nucleotides (AGCT) for pattern of no less and no more than three nucleotides that repeat consecutively at least seven times. I need to also save that combination for print to file as well as a total count.

The pattern of these three nucleotides will be unknown in the sense that while there are only 64 possible combinations, we will not know which one will be the repeating combination.

I have two lines of thought going in my head about how to go about this:

Create a list of the possible combinations and check against that, while producing a count. This doesn't seem feasible because every three nucleotides would produce a match. And it still wouldn't solve the problem of consecutive matching.

OR Check the first three nucleotides against the next three, if matching, check the next three. If no match, shift the reading frame to the second nucleotide in the string and try the search again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex ought to do the trick:

```
/( ([ACGT]{3}) \2{6,} )/x
```

Match three chars of ACGT, then repeat the capture `$2` at least six additional times. The whole matched string is in `$1` and will have three times the length of actual groups: `$n = length($1)/3`.

Test:

```
my $regex = qr/( ([ACGT]{3}) \2{6,} )/x;
"TACGACGACGACGACGACGACGACGT" =~ $regex;
printf "Matched %s exactly %d times\n", $2, length($1)/3;
```

Output:

```
Matched ACG exactly 8 times
```

Looks good.

Comment: It does look good. So I should be able to assign a variable (which would be the user input file) to the "TACGACGACGACGACGACGACGACGT" section. Thank you!